# Extjs session manageemt

Tags: extjs, extjs5, session-management

Wanted to know if there is any way to find when your session is about to expire while using class Ext.data.Session, as the  Ext.data.Session does not provide any event. As per the definition of the class it is used to store  session information with the server data being loaded.

What I want do in my application is user login session management. That is when a user logs in it starts a session and when the session is about the expire I prompt to the user that your session is about to expire. Any event performed in the application resets the session timeout time.

I have checked this [example](http://miamicoder.com/2011/the-art-of-gracefully-handling-session-timeouts-with-extjs/)  on Miami code but as per the logic, the session will be tracked from the time of loging in. But wont be updated whenever there is some event in the application. Hence irrespective of user performing any event the user will be promted that his session is about to expire. This not helping me, as I need to reset the timer if the user performs some activity.

Let me know if I am driving the question in the right direction, else will rephrase accordingly.

Comment: I have an idea check whether it works... if Ext.data.Session is not providing any event .. then write an mouse click or any user operation event on top level container and make the timer reset.

Comment: I tried to use Ext.util.Observable.capture(myObj, function(evname) {console.log(evname, arguments);}) on my view port initialization though could reset timer for any activity in view-port.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Ext.data.Session and User Login Session what you need are two entirely different things.

Ext.data.Session manages data stored in various records such a way that it ensures consistency, uniqueness of the data and saving data to the server.

Thus, Ext.data.Session cannot be used for your purpose.

Comment: How to manage user login session, and have a time out feature for that?

Comment: In a nutshell: When the session expires, the server sends "session expired" response back to Ext. Ext evaluates the reason of failure and redirects the user to a login page.

Comment: Thank you, got the concept. But the system I am using does not validate user session key with each request. Hence it is the responsibility of my client app to manage it. Is there a solutions I can use in this case. I also thought of using a observer on my viewport but is not behaving like intended. So need to have some kind of mechanism for such system.

Comment: Hmm, it's pretty unusual setup, nevertheless it can be implemented. You would have a [global DelayedTask](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask) that would be reset by user actions i.e. when use is inactive it would expire and log him/her off.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. Is there any way I can override all event handling or monitor all event happening or add a global listener for all event on the parent component, here in my case it is viewport.

Comment: If you are asking for the purpose for resetting the delayed task, you don't need to listen to all events. It is enough to listen to the viewport's element click event, with a reasonable buffer, and reset  the delayed task from there. Or you can listen to the global Ajax object: to its beforerequests event.